# Duplicate React Components vs passing props and control behavior/logic

Tags: reactjs

I come from old school html and .asp world and now learning wonderful react world. I am in process of building a small application using react, axios, redux etc. I am trying to simplify my question using below scenario -

Say, I have 4 components based on certain type which I render multiple times using .map()  e.g. Math, History, Language, Arts. All these 4 components have modal forms and logic to show elements based on certain values.

Now, I wish to show these same 4 components in a read-only view that will not have link for modal forms etc.

My Question :

-> Should I just copy these 4 components and make 4 more without the form button?
or
-> Pass prop to these 4 components and add additional logic (in addition to existing that is heavy) to not show the form button?

Basically, are there any guidelines on when to stop passing props/objects/functions and just create separate instance. (4 components vs 8 components in above example)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general terms:

1. D.R.Y. = Do Not Repeat Yourself
2. On my team, at a large American corporation, we limit passing props (aka prop drilling) to 3 layers of nested components.
3. When there are more layers of nesting then destructuring the data you require from your state (ex. Redux) is the way to go.